# iOS how to achieve UIButton's like behavior for nodes in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, sprite-kit, kobold-kit

**I would like some of my Sprite Kit nodes to behave like UIButtons**. I tried 2 approaches:

1) Use `touchesBegan:` - this works if a user is careful, but seems to fire multiple times, faster than I can disable interaction, resulting in a button being able to be activated multiple times:

```
   spriteNode.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

//causes the following to fire when node receives touch
    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        DLog(@"Do node action");
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


    }
```

2)I switched to [Kobold-Kit](http://koboldkit.com/) as a layer on top of iOS Sprite Kit. One of the things it allows me to do is add [button - like behavior](http://koboldkit.com/api/7.0/KoboldKitFree/html/Classes/KKButtonBehavior.html) to any node. However, I'm running into an issue where a if I have 2 buttons stacked on top of each other, tapping the top button activates both. Boolean flags can prevent repeated interactions in this case. I tracked the issue of stacked buttons firing together to this call within KKScene:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    for (id observer in _inputObservers)
    {
        if ([observer respondsToSelector:@selector(touchesBegan:withEvent:)])
        {
            [observer touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
        }
    }
}
```

The scene simply sends notifications to all nodes within the scene. This causes buttons behaviors that are stacked on top of each other to fire together.

Is there a way or example that shows **how to properly arrange sprite nodes to allow behavior similar to UIButton**, where I can have only the top button activate, and each activation disables the button for a short time afterwards?

Comment: With option 1, what happens if you use a local Boolean instead of userInteractionEnabled, could be quicker?

Comment: I tried both, and it seems that touchesBegan: can ignore both.

Answer (score 1):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture;

self.tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureStateChanged:)];
self.tapGesture.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGesture];


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer == self.tapGesture) {
        return CGRectContainsPoint(self.neededSprite.frame, [self convertPoint:[sender locationInView:self.view] toNode:self]);
    }
    return YES;
}



 - (void)tapGestureStateChanged:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
    {
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {
/* do stuff here */
    }
    }
```

Comment: The question is about Sprite Kit nodes, and they are not descendants of UIView.

Comment: And... so? Scene has it's own view property, this solution works fune in my sprite kit game project, it's ok to use UIGestureRecognizers here

Comment: I will take a look at whether the kobold kit scene method for detecting touches can be rewritten using a gesture recognized. This may solve the stacking issue

Answer (score 0):

The  [SpriteKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043) suggests using a SKNode name to gate the behavior that you want to achieve when touched. The example in the section called "Using Actions to Animate Scenes" overrides the touchesBegan:withEvent: method and only runs when the name is not nil. When you're done, just reset the name so that you can catch the next touch.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    SKNode *helloNode = [self childNodeWithName:@"helloNode"];
    if (helloNode != nil) {
        helloNode.name = nil;
        SKAction *moveUp = [SKAction moveByX: 0 y: 100.0 duration: 0.5];
        SKAction *zoom = [SKAction scaleTo: 2.0 duration: 0.25];
        SKAction *pause = [SKAction waitForDuration: 0.5];
        SKAction *fadeAway = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration: 0.25];
        SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
        SKAction *moveSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveUp, zoom, pause, fadeAway, remove]];
        [helloNode runAction: moveSequence];
    }
}
```

Another idea would be to perform your re-enabling of the user interaction to touchesEnded.